# Execute several while true java programs in terminal at the same time

Tags: java, bash, shell, terminal

I have a big question, i want to execute a java program like this, I want to process 100 files at the same time and enter the file number as an argument

```
public class infiniteloop {
  public static void main(String[] argv){
     while(true){
         // set the texfile name with argv[0]
         // waiting for start 
         //read and process a text
     }
  }
}
```

I tried to do with this code, but when I try to run it you get stuck on the execution of the first program

```
#!bin/bash
java -c .:somejar.jar infiniteloop 100001
java -c .:somejar.jar infiniteloop 100002
.
.
.
```

never gets to run the second command, maybe creating new instances of terminal? new tabs and execute each one in a new tab?, the work is in a remote server with ssh.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `&` character to the end of each command run each process in the background:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -c .:somejar.jar infiniteloop 100001 &
java -c .:somejar.jar infiniteloop 100002 &
...
java -c .:somejar.jar infiniteloop <last filename>
```

Each process will start in the background so the script can continue with the next command.

Also note the missing `/` in: `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

add an "&" at the end of the first line

```
java -c .:somejar.jar infiniteloop 100001 &
java -c .:somejar.jar infiniteloop 100002
```

it will make it run in the background, hence it will continue to run the second command.

Comment: AND add "wait" at the end of the file.  Otherwise the script will terminate and kill all child processes.  "wait" will force it to wait until they all exit.  Why exactly are you trying to run dozens of infinite loops?

Comment: @Wug since these are two different `processes` which do not share any resource, I believe that you're wrong.

Comment: I can't try it, I'm at work and on windows.  How about you give it a shot?  I have however run into this very problem, even so similar as running java programs.  The script was terminating as soon as it had launched its children and it was taking all of its children with it, I solved it by adding wait.

Comment: @Wug when a `process` exits it terminates all its child processes, that's true. But, this is not the case here as these are different processes that just happen to runs the same code.

Comment: I don't see why that would stop bash from killing all of the javas it had spawned when it exits.

Comment: @Wup run: `ps -ef | grep java` and see that these are two DIFFERENT processes. when one process ends bash doesn't just go and terminates a different process which is not related in any way. If it still doesn't make any sense to you, please read: http://theunixgeek.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/understanding-linux-processes/

Comment: I had a script to launch about 150 jobs on a parallel cluster in exactly this manner, and if I did not include "wait", each and every one of them was killed when the script finished.  Go test it yourself: launch gedit from shell with `gedit &`, then kill the shell.

Comment: I got the feeling that we're talking about two different things... I say that infiniteloop process cannot kill another infiniteloop process and you're referring to the script itself... adding `"$@"` at the end of each line should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to include the `&` character at the end of each line, so your code will look like

```
#!bin/bash
java -c .:somejar.jar infiniteloop 100001 &
java -c .:somejar.jar infiniteloop 100002 &
```

Note that this is a feature of Bash and not the java process itself.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Java threads. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

This explains it very well
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

```
class ThreadDemo
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
           MyThread mt = new MyThread(arg[i]);
           mt.start()
   }
}
class MyThread extends Thread
{
   String file_name;
   public MyThread(String file_name){
      this.file_name = file_name;
   public void run (){
      while(true){
         // set the texfile name with argv[0]
         //read and process a text
      }
   }
}
```

Its not the best way to do it, but it should work